# Usage of # in Pascal

Tags: pascal

Q1: What does this mean: `WriteLn (#$0b)`?

`$0b` should hexadecimal like `0x0b`, but what about the `#` sign?

Q2:

```
x:=readkey;
if ( x = #5) do...
```

Does `#5` mean five? Then what is the`#` sign for?

Many thanks.

Comment: (Note that in (even not so) recent Delphi and FPC versions larger numbers than 255 are widechars, 16-bit base entity used a base for UTF16 string types)

Answer (score 7):

The `#` in front of a number represents a *character* with the indicated value (both decimal, and hex numbers preceded by a `$`, are accepted). So `#5` is the same as `chr(5)`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Had to look up [`chr`](http://physinfo.ulb.ac.be/cit_courseware/pascal/pas036.htm) for this answer to help, but at least I knew to look up `chr`. `chr(65) = #65 = 'A'`

Comment: Not always. In D3..D2007 and FPC, you can afaik define a widechar with #$1234 and chr() will only return a byte value. I'm away from my development machine so can't quickly test  const xx= #$1234; begin  writeln(sizeof(xx), sizeof(chr($1234))); end.

Answer (score 2):

*Ah, memories ...*

`#x` is indeed the equivalent of `chr(x)`, like [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423875/usage-of-in-pascal/2423907#2423907) said.

I'd like to add a little info.
Extended keys, ie the arrow keys, send zero and the char's code:

```
  ch := ReadKey;
  if ch = #0 then
  begin // extended key
    ch := ReadKey; // <-- read again to get the actual code
  end else ...
```